# Setting up a VB.net BitCoin transfer application

Tags: vb.net, transfer, bitcoin

I need to create an application that can accept BitCoin donations.  I will have clients sending the data and a server to collect the results.  Now, I have my own BitCoin account (on http://ww.MyBitCoin.com) but how would I transfer coins automatically from the client to my server where it will then be added to my account?

Comment: MyBitCoin.com is now defunct - the victim of another hacking attempt. The rest of this information is correct and unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain what you're asking here.

You want your application to send coins from a remote machine to your server? Due to the nature of bitcoins, this isn't possible. What you can do, however, is ask for donations, and give out your receiving address, which is almost like an account number at a bank. There is a page at http://www.weusecoins.com/ that will tell you how to get a receiving address, I highly recommend reading that site.